# How to sign .apk with a custom tool by overriding default behavior of android gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I need to use a custom command line tool to sign my release .apks (the tool sends the .apk to a separate machine for signing). How can I override the signing step generated by the android gradle plugin?

Comment: Inelegant, but if you don't figure out anything better, you could always strip the certificate and re-sign.